# Can I stop an RSpec test run in the middle?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Sometimes after I start the rspec tests, I realized that I wanted to change something; and if it's a long run I would love to be able to stop it in the middle, change whatever it was, and rerun the tests.  Would someone tell me if that is possible and if it is, how to do it?

Comment: Press Control-C? Or were you looking for something programmatic?

Comment: It's ctrl-C twice. Thanks :) Feel free to post it as the answer and I then can check it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can stop the RSpec test in the middle by pressing ctrl-C twice.

Comment: What if tests run in Continuous Integration (jenkins etc)?

Answer (score 0):

As @zetetic said, press Control-C. Or, if you're running from an IDE, click the stop button for the test (not the server or other code you're testing!)